# Ink tutorial Contract UI websocket connection error

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node

Following https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/ink-workshop/pt1/ ,
I run `substrate-contracts-node --dev` to start the node, but the Contract UI at https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ shows `Connection Error` and cannot connect to Local Node, preventing contract deployment.

Any configuration to be changed ?

Running on Chrome, Apple M1 chip.

[image]

**EDIT**: it looks like a websocket connection error:

```
2022-04-22 14:50:15 Blocked connection to WebSockets server from untrusted origin: Some("https://paritytech.github.io")
```

how can we allow the connection?

**EDIT2**: I've added `--unsafe-ws-external` to  `substrate-contracts-node` command and Contract UI connects to LocalNode, but not sure this is the correct solution.
(https://github.com/openethereum/parity-ethereum/issues/9678)

Comment: Can you add which browser you are using?

Comment: @AlexanderTheißen running on Chrome , Apple M1 chip. 
Chrome error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9944/' failed: 
connect @ polkadot.25fc112e.js:23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error happens when the local node is not ran in development mode - need to run `substrate-contracts-node --dev` (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/issues/50)

the problem was that I was running the executable from https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node/releases, that starts the node in Local Testnet (instead of dev)